# MacPro ignoring mouse

Tags: usb, hardware, mouse, macos

MacPro Mid 2012; quad core 3.2 GHz Xeon processor 24 GB ram
running Yosemite 10.10.5

4 internal 4 TB drives, 2 external 4 TB drives in NewTech cradles.
3 Dell 1920 x1280 pixel LCD monitors.

Microsoft USB corded mouse.

Stopped working yesterday.

Rebooted. Mouse cursor shows up, but doesn’t move with mouse.

Tried different mouse.

Tried different USB port

No joy.

More information:

ALL USB access stops.

Rebooting is not sufficient.

Have to fully unplug, and restart.

(It may be sufficient to reset the PRAM on reboot.  didn't try that.)

Further:  I can now reproduce the problem:  If I connect my iphone 6s to my mac with a 3 meter Lightning **to USB** cable, the mouse (and USB) stops working.

On shutdown there is a long stream (several screenfulls of probe error messages that flash by.

```
2017-12-23 10:01:03.000 PM kernel[0]: [0 0  ] target connection status changed
2017-12-23 10:01:03.000 PM kernel[0]: [0 0  ] port handle error (irq status 80000040)
```

This pair appears about 100 times per second grovelling through the system log.

Connecting with an official apple 1 meter Lightning cable works.

Comment: Tried safe mode? Reset NVRAM & SMC?

Comment: *If I connect my iphone 6s to my mac with a 3 meter thunderbolt cable*  Huh?  Do you mean a USB to *Lightning* cable?  And when you connect with the official Apple cable, are you referring to your mouse or your iPhone?

Comment: there are thunderbolt to thunderbolt cables?  Yes, that's what I meant.  I don't have a young enough mac to have apple's latest port.

Comment: Please double check what you are using.  There's no such thing as a TB to mouse or TB to iPhone cable.    If you're not sure what you've got connected to what and how, feel free to take a picture so we can see what you're seeing.

Comment: Can you update the question with your exact Mac Pro model and OS X version? As @Tetsujin suggested, I would reset both the NVRAM and SMC.

Comment: @Allan I know of no mouse with a replaceable cable.  I know of no thunderbolt mouse.  To make it clear though, it was the Official Apple thunderbold USB cord that when used instead of the unoffical thunderbolt USB cord that allowed the rodent with it's built in USB cord to work.

Comment: @Jake3231 Done.

Comment: **There is no such thing as a Thunderbolt to USB cable. Period.**  The [MacPro 2012](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP652?locale=en_US) doesn't even have TB ports so you couldn't plug a TB cable in if you tried.  If when you plug in your *USB to Lightning cable* for you iPhone causes a lock up - [get a new cable from a reputable manufacturer](http://amzn.to/2Dntobr)

Comment: My bad.  Replace thunderbolt with lighting in all previous topics.  I will edit the problem.